# whats missing this regex to match the lines of apache logs?

Tags: python, regex

I have these lines

```
5.10.80.69 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:20 -0700] "PATCH /niches/back-end HTTP/2.0" 406 15834
11.57.203.39 - carroll8889 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:21 -0700] "HEAD /visionary/cultivate HTTP/1.1" 404 15391
124.137.187.175 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:22 -0700] "DELETE /expedite/exploit/cultivate/web-enabled HTTP/1.0" 403 2606
203.36.55.39 - collins6322 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:23 -0700] "PATCH /efficient/productize/disintermediate HTTP/1.1" 504 13377
175.5.52.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:24 -0700] "POST /real-time HTTP/1.1" 200 2660
232.220.131.214 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:25 -0700] "GET /wireless/matrix/synergistic/expedite HTTP/1.1" 205 15081
87.234.209.125 - labadie6990 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:26 -0700] "GET /unleash/aggregate HTTP/2
```

and I need to put them in an array like this:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

This is what I have done:

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        return logdata
    
partes = [
    r'(?P<host>\S+)',                   # host %h
    r'\S+',                             # indent %l (unused)
    r'(?P<user>\S+)',                   # user %u
    r'\[(?P<time>.+)\]',                # time %t
    r'"(?P<request>.*)"',               # request "%r"
    r'(?P<status>[0-9]+)',              # status %>s
    r'(?P<size>\S+)',                   # size %b (careful, can be '-')
    r'"(?P<referrer>.*)"',              # referrer "%{Referer}i"
    r'"(?P<agent>.*)"',                 # user agent "%{User-agent}i"
]

pattern = re.compile(r'\s+'.join(partes)+r'\s*\Z')

log_data = []

for line in logs():
  log_data.append(pattern.match(line).groupdict())
    
print (log_data)
```

But I have this errror:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-029948b6e367> in <module>
     23 # Get components from each line of the log file into a structured dict
     24 for line in logs():
---> 25   log_data.append(pattern.match(line).groupdict())
     26 
     27 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

This error is obviusly because the regex is wrong, but not sure why, the code is taken from here:

https://gist.github.com/sumeetpareek/9644255

Update:

```
    import re
    def logs():
        with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
            logdata = file.read()
            return logdata

regex="^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$"

log_data = []

for line in logs():
    m = pattern.match(line)
    log_data.append(re.findall(regex, line).groupdict())
    
print (log_data)
```

But I get this error:unexpected character after line continuation character

Update 2:

when adding the items to a dictionary, the items must arrive in this format:

assert len(logs()) == 979

```
one_item={'host': '146.204.224.152',
  'user_name': 'feest6811',
  'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
  'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
assert one_item in logs(), "Sorry, this item should be in the log results, check your formating"
```

Comment: what do you mean? the patter is not in comments

Comment: the question is not duplicate! its not even similar!, the question is about whats wrong with regex, not how to split a regex in multiple lines

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(line)` in the loop?

Comment: I think the solution is to fix the `logs` function so that it returns something that actually iterates over the *lines*, not the *characters*.

Comment: can you please clarify further as an answer?

Comment: Ok, the pattern is really not what you need. `"(?P<referrer>.*)"\s+"(?P<agent>.*)"` is just not present in your strings. What do you want to match in the last line? That is, let alone the fact that you read the whole file contents into a single line, and that certainly will never work with a pattern having a `\Z` anchor when you expect multiple matches.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Just using `file.readlines()` or similar won't work. The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vEuWvi/1) just does not match anything.

Comment: Okay, then there's more than one problem I guess.

Comment: found the regex: ^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+)\s?(\S+)?\s?(\S+)?" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)\s?"?([^"]*)"?\s?"?([^"]*)?"?$

Comment: And you also need the `re.M` flag then, if you still use `file.read()`.

Comment: see the update please! I am close

Comment: Well, you forgot to escape `"`. Use `r'''....'''` to delimit the pattern string literal. Anyway, your last line is not matched correctly.

Comment: dont worry about the lastline, I pasted it incomplete.. sorry about that

Comment: when I add r' I get this: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are a lot of issues with the solution you have, please consider revamping it completely.

The regex that should work for you is

```py
^(?P<host>\S+) +\S+ +(?P<user>\S+) +\[(?P<time>[\w:/]+ +[+-]\d{4})] +"(?P<request>\S+) +(?P<status>\S+) +(?P<size>\S+)" +(?P<someid>\d{3}|-) +(?P<someid2>\d+|-)(?: +"(?P<referrer>[^"]*)"(?: +"(?P<agent>[^"]*)")?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJd6UY/2). Note the last `(?: +"([^"]*)"(?: +"([^"]*)")?)?` part matches two optional sequences of patterns and the last one is only matched if the first is matched.

The code you can leverage may look like

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''^(?P<host>\S+) +\S+ +(?P<user>\S+) +\[(?P<time>[\w:/]+ +[+-]\d{4})] +"(?P<request>\S+) +(?P<status>\S+) +(?P<size>\S+)" +(?P<someid>\d{3}|-) +(?P<someid2>\d+|-)(?: +"(?P<referrer>[^"]*)"(?: +"(?P<agent>[^"]*)")?)?$''')

log_data = []

with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    m = pattern.search(line.strip())
    if m:
      log_data.append(m.groupdict())

print(log_data)
```

[**See the Python demo**](https://ideone.com/rQVSfs)

Comment: thank you, but this only returns me an array of empty objects: [{}, {}, {}, etc...

Comment: @LuisValencia Put back the named groups, and it will.  See https://ideone.com/rQVSfs, I am just not sure what the group names must be.

Comment: there is one caveat that I still dont know how to fix, the regex works perfectly fine, but it  splits the request into several groups,  but in order for the exercise to be good, the request should be one group alone:  (see update 2).

Comment: @LuisValencia Then why complicate the pattern in the first place? Use `r'''^(?P<host>\S+) +\S+ +(?P<user_name>\S+) +\[(?P<time>[^][]+)] +"(?P<request>[^"]+)"'''`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJd6UY/3).